# Getting CDATA[Line length limit 100 exceeded.] for multipart/formdata in soapUI even though the content length is not exceeding 100

Tags: rest, soapui, multipartform-data

I am doing Post method on SoapUI where post body content-Type is multipart/formdata.
In the body few values are proper string values whereas one value is Json value. See the example below

**Form-data(example) start:**

Name1 : aravind

age : 24

Details:{"Height":"170cms",
"weight":"70kgs",
"Education":{"Primary":"xyz",
"Degree":"abc"}}

**Form-data(example) End**

For the above form data i have give post body like below in the soapUI but i am getting **CDATA[Line length limit 100 exceeded.]** ERROR

**Header**

Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary="123121"

**PostBody in SoapUI:**

--123121

Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Name1"

aravind

--123121

Content-Disposition:form-data; name="age"

24

--123121

Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Details"

{"Height":"170cms", "weight":"70kgs", "Education":{"Primary":"xyz", "Degree":"abc"}}

--123121--

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I cant provide the URL. but there is no groovy script or any other code involved. it is multipart/form-data with "key-values" similar to given example and i have provided  post body as mentioned above.  Created a simple rest request(Post Method) with the mentioned data and just triggered it. with that i am getting the error